# How to check if there's a repeat?

Tags: ruby

```
    randomized = 10.times.map { Random.new.rand(1..100) }
```

I wanted to make 10 randomized numbers that do not repeat twice. How do I check it? I don't want to do the long one such as

```
    puts randomized[0] != randomized[1]
    puts randomized[1] != randomized[2]
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want all ten to be entirely unique, or that you do not want a number to repeat the previous one?

Comment: When asking it's important to show us what you tried. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is good to read, along with "[ask]" and its linked pages.

Comment: Sidenote: `Random.new` creates a PRNG, a Pseudo Random Number Generator. This generator generates just one number and then an new generator is constructed. Just `Random.rand(1..100)` or even plain `rand(1..100)`  is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) takes an argument:

```
randomized = (1..100).to_a.sample(10) #=> [52, 100, 92, 93, 33, 66, 78, 84, 36, 98]
```

From the docs: " The elements are chosen by using random and unique indices into the array in order to ensure that an element doesn’t repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements."

Answer (score 2):

You could just shuffle and array of the given set to guarantee no dups.

```
randomized = (1..100).to_a.shuffle
```

You can then just pop them off

```
next_r = randomized.pop
```

Comment: Even better, just chop off the first ten all at once:  `(1..100).to_a.shuffle[0,10]`